# excel only show rows with difference values

Tags: excel, diff

Hi oh you all wise people.

Not sure if it is doable.. But here goes.

I have a "master" sheet with a set field set (it is the same fieldset I extract every time)

Sheet1:

```
  A B   C
-----------
1 B 2   BA
2 C 5   AB
```

Sheet3:

```
  A B   C
-----------
1 B 1   BA
2 C 5   AB
```

Since B:2 has been changed from 2 to 1, it should result in:

Sheet2:

```
  A B   C
-----------
1 B 2   BA
```

I would like to get the changes between my "master" sheet and the "next extraction" of data.

The challenge (I think) is that I only want the rows with changes displayed in a third sheet.

```
Sheet1 : Master Data
Sheet2 : Diff Reporting
Sheet3 : Weekly Extraction
```

Anyone?

Comment: can you post a picture of your data? maybe you can copy both lists into sheet3 and use the `remove duplicates` method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following dot.Py's suggestion, I would:

- Copy both row sets to a new sheet
- Add a column showing which sheet each row originally came from, let's call it "Source".
- Use the 'Remove Duplicates' feature in the Data tab, but do not use the "Source" column as a duplicate criteria. (http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/remove-duplicates.html)
- After removing duplicates you'll have both the old and new row for rows that have changed.
- Filter based on the "Source" column and then delete any rows from the old sheet.